# sympy undefined function of many variables

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to conduct some functional analysis in sympy with a function from R^N-->R^N. I am hoping to make a function of N variables and have undefined partial derivatives for every variable. I have found that I want to create symbols using the slice notation

```
vars = symbols('a1:10')
```

I then attempt to make a function of these variables with

```
f = Function('f')(vars)
```

and already I see there will be a problem as I've created a function of a tuple of my variables, not a function of my variables. Not surprisingly,

```
f.diff(vars[0])
```

generates an error that 'Tuple' object has no attribute 'diff'.

Is there an easy way to fix the way I've declared my function or perhaps to define diff for tuples such that I can find my partials? I need the slice declaration of variables because I am hoping to do this for an arbitrary number of variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpacking your tuple will help you with the first step:

```
>>> v=var('x:10')
>>> f=Function('f')
>>> f(*v)
f(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9)
```